# How can I to remove meta tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[image]

```
<meta name="geo.region" content="el-gr" />
```

Is it possible to remove the meta tags just by using JavaScript?

Comment: i think the question is why...what do you attempt to achieve by doing this

Comment: Note while you can remove it with js unless you are then rewriting the page file with the modified code it is just going to return when the page is loaded again. It doesnt modify the file in place. Also it doesnt affect the currently loaded page or any outside request to the page eg facebook/twitter scraper

Comment: @Ctznkane525 It's for a captive portal on a router and I've access only the body section of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the element & Remove it.

```
document.querySelector("[name='geo.region']").remove()
```

this will remove the first meta in the webpage with name having `geo.region`

Or using jQuery

```
$("[name='geo.region']").remove()
```

Comment: Note the selector you are using in the jquery snippet can be used with querySelector as well it isnt using any special jquery selectors

Comment: The vanillajs version will throw an error if there is no matching element.

Comment: The first code will throw error if no element is found. Use this instead `(document.querySelector("[name='geo.region']") || {remove:()=>0}).remove()`